# WPF window inside a WinformHost Panel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms-interop

I am showing a WPF exe window inside another WPF application using winform host.

I have created a panel in main application and set it as child of winformhost.

```
  mHostingPanel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
            {
                BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            };                


            mWinformHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
            mWinformHost.Child = mHostingPanel;
```

and then I start the other window process and set hosting panel as parent.

```
  WindowsAPI.SetParent(mProcess.MainWindowHandle, mHostingPanel.Handle);
```

My question is if I launch the application,Who will be rendering my Child WPF window whose parent is a winform panel.Will it be Direct-X or GDI context of Panel?

Also if I set Allowtransparency=True on child WPF application,The UI doesnt show up in hosting panel.

Comment: This is evil, and not necessarily in a bad way!

Comment: I don't think that taking ownership of the window will impact the wpf rendering at all.  I would look at this though: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683/

Comment: @tolanj: If you read that blog entry you cannot possible arrive at the conclusion, that this weren't necessarily evil. In a very, **very** bad way. That other application is most certainly not prepared to be re-parented. If it were, it'd be an ActiveX control.

Comment: The real question isn't, who's responsible for rendering. The **real** question is: Does input still work? And the answer to that question is: No. It **will** deadlock at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.Its called airspace issue (when win32 and WPF trying to share pixels) and I dont think it can be solved by any framework API as microsoft denied it.
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2644120-bring-back-the-hwndhost-isredirected-and-compositi

[Mitigating AirSpace issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications/)